# Source of a "Copy Activity" as "List of files" doesn't preserve the listed files order

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

in a Synapse Analytics pipeline, I'm using a copy activity to merge several .csv files (each one contains 1 single row) into a single one. I would like the resulting .csv to preserve the alphabetical order of the individual .csv files, thus I tried to configure the Source as a "List of files" as File path type: [ListofFiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2utsf.png) and I upload on my storage a .txt file containing the list of individual csv, in alphabetical order.

It works fine, but the global csv doesn't keep the rows in the expected order (i.e. following the given order of the individual csv files).

Is there a way to achieve this?
thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1076037/merge-multiple-files-in-order-using-azure-data-fac
ADF copy  behavior doesn't have control over the order of files to be merged and also the order of rows to be merged. It considers randomly.

Comment: ok, that's a crystal-clear answer, thanks! @DileeprajnarayanThumula

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce using the copy activity to merge .csv files into 1 file using the List of files option.

**Source:**
In the ADLS I have 3 csv file and 1 .txt file which have the metadata of the 3 files.
[image]
I have used the Source as the below:
[image]
In sink, I have tried 2 options to achieve the order by
I have tried using Merge files and Preserve hirerarchy copy behavior.

[image]
[image]

When I use the **MERGE** files the output merge all 3 files.
But the order is as below
[image]
When using the Preserve hirerarchy
[image]

As per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1076037/merge-multiple-files-in-order-using-azure-data-fac) copy `mergeFiles` behavior doesn't have control over the order of files to be merged and also the order of rows to be merged. It considers randomly.

Comment: thanks again for your time trying this. I think that there is no solution for now. I will keep it with this 'random' order, not a big deal.